# DataTables - How can I use my own buttons for exporting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, datatables, materialize

I'm using Materialize as my UI framework and I'm using DataTables for my tables. I have a table which I need to export to excel and I can do it just fine using the DataTables buttons. However, they are the default DataTables buttons, and I would like to use the Materialize buttons.

So the question is: **how can I use my own buttons and have them do the functions of the built-in buttons of DataTables (specifically exporting to Excel)?**

I already tried using the option "className" to the Materialize button class, but that didn't work. I figure I probably will have to do some JQuery function.

Thanks everyone!

EDIT: Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var dataTable = $('#datatable').DataTable( {
    language: {
        search: "",
        searchPlaceholder: "Search"
    },
    dom: 'Brftip',
    buttons: [
        'copy',
        'csv',
        'excel',
        'pdf',
        'print'
    ]
} );
```

Comment: Show your code please!

Comment: @CMedina thank you. It's pretty standard DataTables code. Check the EDIT on my main post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`buttons.dom.button`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/buttons.dom.button) to define class and element that would be used for a button.

For example:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "ajax": 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/qgcu',
    "order": [],
    "dom": 'Bfrtip',        
    "buttons": {
       "dom": {
          "button": {
            "tag": "button",
            "className": "waves-effect waves-light btn mrm"
          }
       },
       "buttons": [ 'copyHtml5', 'excelHtml5', 'csvHtml5', 'pdfHtml5' ]   
    }
});
```

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ey891een/1/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Yep, you got it! Thank you so much! I don't want to push my luck or anything, but you also wouldn't know how to change the pagination to the Materialize pagination, would you? If you don't then don't worry, I'll try to figure it out on my own. But again, thank you very much!

Comment: @T.Ferreira, this is just a hack, but see this example https://jsfiddle.net/ey891een/2/

Comment: Nice! I'm going to see if I can improve it tomorrow. But thank you so much, you've been an amazing help!

Comment: Again, thank you! You've been really great! You seem to know a lot about DataTables so do you mind if I pick your brain a little bit more? I have a button to add a new item to the table and I use a Modal for that. So when a user clicks that button a modal pops up with a form with the details of the item. I'm using the Modals from Materialize (see here: http://materializecss.com/modals.html). This is my code for that button: `<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">New Item</a>`.

Comment: So what I want to do is align this button with the other buttons (excel, copy, etc). I though about maybe creating a custom DataTables button that does the same function as this one, but that would require the ability to give an id to the button, which doesn't seem possible with DataTables. In order for the modal to work, it has to have an id, as you can see in the Materialize site. Do you know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/custom

```
buttons: [
    {
        text: 'Reload',
        action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                dt.ajax.reload();
            }
        }
    ]
```

"text" can be the html to your custom button

Comment: You have provided a code for a custom button. However OP wanted to style existing buttons differently instead.

Comment: You are right, i should have been more specific : 
To me a button is some html and a click action. 
So i proposed to create a new button with the desired aspect instead of modifying the original ones. 
This can be translated to : 
    
buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'csvHtml5',
                text: "<div class='myClass'><img src='csv.png' ></div>"
        }
    ]

Comment: I don't think that will work either, since button would still have default styling with `div` inside.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Jquery to select the button and add the class in the drawcallback.  Something like this:

```
$('.buttons-excel').addClass('waves-effect waves-light btn');
```

Or:

```
 var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "ajax": 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/qgcu',
    "order": [],
    "dom": 'Bfrtip',        
    "buttons": {
    "dom": {
       "button": {
        "tag": "button",
        "className": "waves-effect waves-light btn mrm"
       }
    },
     "buttons": [ 'copyHtml5', 'excelHtml5', 'csvHtml5', 'pdfHtml5' ]   
   }
 });
```

Comment: Thank you! That doesn't work, friend. You don't need JQuery for that, DataTables has a "className" option for the buttons and I already tried it, like I said in my post. However, the button doesn't look like the Materialize ones. Here's a screenshot (the first row is how I want them to look like, the second is how they look like): http://i.imgur.com/VN08uro.png

Comment: Ah sorry I misread.  I'm not expert I can admit that.  I wanted to use bootstrap buttons on my data table and could only get it working by doing the addClass in my "drawCallback"