# How to hook up custom buttons instead of the DataTables buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I have some custom buttons on a page, that I would like to replicate the functionally of the *DataTables* buttons. I am using *DataTables* because I can quickly export to Excel and PDF. I do not need the searching, filtering or other features of *DataTables* for this project. So if you have suggestions on a better way, I'm willing to listen.

I have looked at the DataTables custom button, (Thats how I got the PRINT button) but I can't seem to find a way of using my buttons instead.

**Does anyone know a way how to use custom buttons?**

[image]

```
<div class="col-6">
      <div class="col d-print-none">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary float-right m-1"  onclick="window.print();"><i class="fas fa-print"></i> Print Report</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success float-right m-1"  onclick=""><i class="fas fa-file-excel"></i> Export to Excel</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger float-right m-1"  onclick=""><i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i> Download as PDF</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary float-right m-1"  onclick=""><i class="fas fa-clipboard"></i> Copy to Clipboard</button>
      </div>
   </div>
```

The `DataTables` code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $('#dataTableDetails').DataTable({
           "deferRender": true,
           "ordering": false,
           "paging": false,
           "info": false,
           "searching": false,
           dom: 'Bfrtip',
           buttons: [
               'copyHtml5',
               'excelHtml5',
               'csvHtml5',
               'pdfHtml5',
               {
                   text: 'PRINT',
                   action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                      window.print();
                   }
               }
           ]
       });
   } );
```

Comment: You can set the ' text: 'my custom text' ' for all the above buttons.

Comment: But I don't want to use DataTables built in buttons, I want to use my own.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, No onclick events needed other than for Print. Basically call the classes of the default buttons

```
   <div class="col-6">
      <div class="col d-print-none">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary float-right m-1" onclick="window.print();"><i class="fas fa-print"></i> Print Report</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success buttons-excel float-right m-1"><i class="fas fa-file-excel"></i> Export to Excel</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger buttons-pdf float-right m-1"><i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i> Download as PDF</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary buttons-copy float-right m-1"><i class="fas fa-clipboard"></i> Copy to Clipboard</button>
      </div>
   </div>
```

You can check these threads for more information;
[How to call Datatable csv button from custom button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45515559/how-to-call-datatable-csv-button-from-custom-button)

[DataTables - How can I use my own buttons for exporting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37595323/datatables-how-can-i-use-my-own-buttons-for-exporting)

Answer (score 0):

The DataTables plugin has an extension that allows you to add custom buttons, you can find the documentation for this here: https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/custom. You can use this in coordination with the dom field to move or set the default and custom buttons as you need. Documentation for this is here: https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom

Comment: But that builds out the datatables buttons.

Answer (score 0):

First, in order to remove those button, you need exclude from `buttons`
Second, in order to create custom button events, you need get your datatable instance then manual fire your event.